# Connection Error with .NET 3.5 and C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, database-connection

So I originally created this program for .NET 4.5 but then found out that the target machines that I'm making it for is for .NET 3.5. When I'm trying to connect to a database I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provier is not registered on the local machine.
```

I have installed the AccessDatabaseEngine.exe (2010) on the machine, but yet it still I still get the same error message. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? The connection string in my code looks like this:

```
connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLDEB.12.0;Data Source=S:\dispatch\AIS\Database\AIS_be.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
```

Comment: Did you install the right version? X64?

Comment: I had this problem when I installed the 32bit engine and the assembly was compiled to 64bit.

Comment: Just checked, and I can't install the x64 since I have a 32-Bit MS Office products installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot install the x64, you can change the Solution Platform from "Any CPU" to "x86"：

1. Right Click "Solution File" in Solution Explorer
2. Click "Configuration Manager".
3. Click "Active Platform", Select x86.
4. Compile and Run again.